# Apache Mod Rewrite not redirecting on Empty URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have a domain http://www.foobar.com

underneath this document root are two directories:  foo & bar

I wanted to create a rewrite rule so that anyone just going to http://www.foobar.com is redirected to http://www.foobar.com/foo

but it would leave anyone going to all other real directories alone.

so for example:

```
http://www.foobar.com -> http://www.foobar.com/foo
http://www.foobar.com/bar -> http://www.foobar.com/bar
```

I would think having something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$  foo/ [L]
```

would work but it doesnt

any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's in your vHost config you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$  /foo/ [L]
```

Comment: that didn't work for me.  it wasn't redirecting anything.

I know its actually getting to that rule because if I put in RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/ [L] it will redirect on the empty URI, but also on anything else so bar/ -> foo as well

Comment: Where are you including this rule? In an `.htaccess` file at the server root or in an `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Odd - the same worked fine for me. Modify the `[L]` to `[L,R]` so you can see a more obvious redirect (instead of an internal rewrite). Any change?